# Equality on classes

Tags: soft-question, category-theory

On every set $A$ there is an equality $=_A$ defined. This is necessary to speak about injectivity, surjectivity, the group axioms and so ...

In category theory, one uses classes to be collections of objects. I wonder, if there should always be an equality defined on classes. That is, if I have a category $\mathcal{C}$ and two objects $a, b\in \mathrm{ob}(\mathcal{C})$, am I allowed to ask the question whether $a = b$? In the case $\mathrm{ob}{\mathcal{C}}$ I am allowed to ask this question. But when it comes to proper classes I am not sure anymore. For example, consider the category of sets $\mathrm{Sets}$. When I fix two sets $A, B$ I am not always allowed to ask whether these sets $A, B$ are equal because, as I learned from Lawvere's book "Sets for Mathematics",

> A set is supposed to have elements, each of which
>   has no structure, and is itself supposed to have no internal structure, except that the
>   elements can be distinguished as equal or unequal, and to have no external structure
>   except for the number of elements

Comment: Yes, you can ask whether $a=b$ for $a,b\in ob(C)$, because $a,b$ are *sets*.

Comment: Can you explain this? One can ask whether $A\cong B$ but why can one alsways ask whether $A = B$ for sets $A, B$?

Comment: ZFC's first axiom basically defines $=$ between two sets.

Comment: @Berci: I am sorry to hear that you use ZFC.

Comment: By the Axiom of Extensionality, which defines equality of sets. @asdjdjje You use ZFC too.

Comment: I actually don't think that this is a bad question, but it's really a question about categorical foundations, and it should be rewritten to make that clear. It seems like asdjdjje want's to ask "How do categorical foundations such as ETCS (as described in "Sets for Mathematics") handle proper classes? In particular, (1) can we make sense of the equality relation between elements of proper classes in these systems? (2) how are large categories formalized in these systems?"

Comment: Does this match your intention, asdjdjje? The point is that if you're going to ask questions about foundational issues, people are going to assume you're working with the *standard* foundation ZFC unless you say otherwise explicitly.